# Print Single Value from SQL Server Database using C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

How can I display single value from SQL Server database in C# ?

I have a total of 8 columns in database and I want to display a count of the 4th column in a MessageBox

```
cn.Open();
str = "select count(name) from Student";
cmd = new SqlCommand(str,cn);
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

MessageBox.Show(reader.ToString());

cmd.Dispose();
reader.Close();
cn.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for a single column of a single row, you can use `ExecuteScalar`

```
cn.Open();
str = "select count(name) from Student";
cmd = new SqlCommand(str,cn);
value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

MessageBox.Show(value .ToString());

cmd.Dispose();
cn.Close();
```

If you expect multiple rows, you will need to iterate through each of the rows, using `while (reader.Read())`.